Get "Must Declare Scalar Variable" error when referencing user-defined table type in stored procedure
I am trying to conditionally update a table using a user-defined table type variable passed to a stored procedure. When I say, if the UDTT variable is not null, then do something with the UDTT, I get an error message. However, I get the scalar not declared error, even though I can reference this variable in a SELECT statement.
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[myProc]
    @table [myUDTT] NULL READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    IF @table IS NOT NULL  
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM @table
    END
END

The reference to @table after IF causes the error, however the reference after SELECT does not.
I've tried:

Making the reference as simple as possible.
Changing the @table variable to an INT and the error message was no longer displayed:
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[fakeProc]
    @table int NULL
AS
BEGIN
    IF @table IS NOT NULL 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @table
    END
END



The result I would like is that if the variable is null, the select statement is skipped.

IF @table IS NOT NULL a table cannot be scalarly checked like that, it's either filled or empty, so just write the code like: if exists(select 1 from @table) ...
